# Suggested tag wiki edits need to be accepted and so do their excerpts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

If you look at the tag wiki for [[ternary-operator]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ternary-operator/info) you'll see none displayed. However, if you check the history, I have an [accepted entry](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2599) there.

The problem is I included a terse excerpt which was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2600).

*I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, so I've marked it [discussion].*

Comment: @GraceNote Thanks for adding relevant tags. I was thinking about which of the required tags to add and totally forgot about other ones :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah this is the way I designed it, I wanted to make sure we do the best we can to ensure we do not lose information in these cases. Its a total edge case but still I did not want to lose effort.

So the information is there ... just hidden, waiting for the next editor to bring it out.

Tag wikis without excerpts are pretty useless, so I did not want to pretend we have a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is a bug. An excerpt can be suggested by one person and a wiki by another.
So the pair acceptance cannot work.
Your wiki suggestion was accepted and your excerpt was only accepted by one so it is rejected.
Try again ? , maybe they could have improved on it / edited also.